# What is the difference between style sheets and inline styles?

Tags: css, javafx

As described from the JavaFX CSS reference guide:

> CSS styles can come from style sheets or inline styles. Style sheets
>   are loaded from the URLs specified in the stylesheets variable of the
>   Scene object. If the scene graph contains a Control, a default user
>   agent style sheet is loaded. Inline styles are specified via the Node
>   setStyle API. Inline styles are analogous to the style="..." attribute
>   of an HTML element. Styles loaded from a Scene's style sheets take
>   precedence over rules from the user agent style sheet. Inline styles
>   take  precedence over styles originating elsewhere. The precedence
>   order of style rules can be modified using "!important" in a style
>   declaration.

What exactly does this mean and what is the difference between the two? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can add a class or id to your element and write your favorite style to external file for that and import your external file via <link> tag to your main html file. it is so important for google not to use inline styles. i suggest you that use stylesheets files and then import to your main html file. @Desi

Comment: @user2864740 The reason I'm asking is because I don't understand what its stating, "Inline styles take precedence over style rules from the user agent style sheet". The documentation doesn't seem to provide any examples (not that I know of).

Comment: "Inline styles take precedence over style rules from the user agent style sheet" means that if you set the same property both in a stylesheet and in an inline style, the setting in the inline style will be the one that is used.

Answer (score 1):

> > CSS styles can come from style sheets or inline styles.
> >     the styling you see on screen is determined by the compiler reading either a standalone file containing CSS definitions or by specific code you write in your code.
> >
> > Style sheets are loaded from the URLs specified in the stylesheets variable of the Scene object. If the scene graph contains a Control, a default user agent style sheet is loaded.

The location of the style sheets file is predefined for you and exists and is effecting your program whether you did anything to create it or not. The location of that file is described by some String or URL field which itself is located in the Scene object.

> > > Inline styles are specified via the Node setStyle API. Inline styles are analogous to the style="..." attribute of an HTML element.

Inline styles are styles you consciously defined during the writing of code in your classes. You know you did this and how its effecting your application. The code you wrote used certain methods known as the "setStyle API". The "setStyle API" is nothing more than you invoking MyStyleableNode.setStyle("blah blah blah, define my styles in a specific manner here"). That manner is described  somewhere else.

> > > Styles loaded from a Scene's style sheets take precedence over rules from the user agent style sheet. Inline styles take precedence over styles originating elsewhere. The precedence order of style rules can be modified using "!important" in a style declaration.

Now that there are multiple sources of style information, they may conflict with each other and we (the authors of JavaFX) need a way to decide how to adjudicate amongst them. We do that by hard coding a set of precedence rules we promise to always follow. They are:

UserAgent stylesheets have lowest priority. We didn't mention what these were because we like to create lots of questions on StackExchange. Now that you're here, we'll tell you.

UserAgent stylesheets are stylesheets defined In the Application.java class using a specific method namely:

setUserAgentStylesheet(String URL).

Trumping UserAgent Stylesheets is the Scene's stylesheets which we did tell you about (see above).

Trumping both of those is Inline stylesheets (which is really a method invocation in your code and not a "sheet" i.e. independent file, at all). I told you about that above also.

> > The precedence order of style rules can be modified using "!important" in a style declaration.

In case you get yourself thoroughly confused or your manager comes to you one day with an emergency! request to change everything radically, we created a catch-all precedence operator you can append to style sheet rules- written: "!important" - because sometimes you just gotta do what you gotta do.

Answer (score 0):

1- style sheet load separately from main document but inline style load inside your document.
2- inline style affect on load speed and make your site load slower, but style sheet is good on speed.
3- inline style is a bad thing for your website SEO but style sheet is not.
4- inline style is force to apply,I mean it Is compulsory. but in style sheet you had to add `!important` for force!
5- if you use style sheet is more safe to copy / grab your website style, but if you use inline CSS it is easy to copy for rippers!

Comment: Great answer, however as you stated "inline style affect on load speed and make your site load slower", would this make my application load slower? I'm referring to a scene graph, not HTML document.

Comment: in applications is different but is recommended to use style sheet instead inline

Comment: Most of these (1, maybe 2, 3, and 5) do not really apply in a JavaFX application. Using style sheets and manipulating style classes (or, better still, pseudoclasses) will result in better performance than using inline styles.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation James_D, does this mean that inline styles hard-coded in the source-code?